# Is it possible to generate an autofill script for Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to create a script to autofill based on what the respondent is filling out in a short answer or even just suggest text in a dropdown.

For example, there are over 300 different codes, which makes scrolling through that drop down list very annoying.

I want the script to had the ability to suggest an autofill once a user is attempting to type in an answer. For example, typing "T00F1..." would suggest autofilling the rest to "T00F17T0"

That way i prevent that the respondent write wrong the code

If it is not possible, what alternatives do you recommend to generate this type of forms?

Comment: Unfortunately, you wouldn't be able to do this in Apps Script. If you have access you could try looking at [App Maker](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/). It would be more work, but you'd get the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically update Google Form on-the-fly using only Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62404335/dynamically-update-google-form-on-the-fly-using-only-google-script)