# Dynamically update Google Form on-the-fly using only Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Well, I'm not a programmer but I think I can find my self around Google Script. PHP and others are somewhat intimidating for me at this stage :)
I have a form that logs account managers' activities in a sheet named "activities". These activities can be towards either a lead or an account. There's another sheet called "contact list", in the same spreadsheet, which holds the contact details of all such accounts and leads. I have been able to populate a form question dropdown with the names originating from "contact list". The downside is that this formId is updated when a user opens the form, which results in the dropdown containing all names, i.e. both accounts and leads.
How can I update the dropdown based on a previous question "are you updating an activity for a lead or for an account"? I've read numerous other posts, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55448531/dynamically-update-dropdown-based-on-previous-selection-with-php-pdo). All of these are based on PHP and others. I'd like to keep it simple and stay "within" Google Script.
Thanks

---

Here's a [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LoHg53hzQvYtOLTcDwxLY8OrKVN4F7usX8YI41BtdWg/edit?usp=sharing), which includes also a form and script.
As you can see, the script populates the "client name" question in the form and it works fine (script copied from another post, which I cannot find right now. Thanks to author!). However, my goal is to have the first question "client type" populate the second question "client name" with ***only*** the names of the clients which are of the relevant type. How can this be done?

Comment: Please share a demo sheet containing the script (and it's form).

Comment: @marikamitsos Added demo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With Google Apps Script it's not possible to update a Google Form on-the-fly.

Related

- [Dynamic dependent dropdowns on Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58418531/1595451)
- [How to dynamically change an existing text item value on Google Forms using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59270911/1595451)